# Navigation responsive

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-element, wordpress-shortcode

```
var button = document.querySelector(".custom_button");
var header_component = document.getElementById("header_component");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header_component.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Got an error On desktop screen it is worked but in mobile and tablet screen it is not worked in.
By the way I have created a custom header and add a code to add a clickable effect

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Kindly check this website menu it is worked on desktop version but not in mobile version https://demolink.co.uk/gir/